# EPPlus returns Excel file downloaded from SharePoint without any worksheets

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, epplus, .net-7.0

I am using Microsoft Graph to get an excel file from SharePoint, and then I am using EPPlus to convert the IFormFile to an Excel file. This has worked in the past, but we upgraded to .Net 7 recently. Here's what I am using

.Net 7

MS Graph version: 5.39

EPPlus version: 7.0.6

Here is my code for getting the file from SharePoint: (FYI - DAFormFile inheirets from IFormFile)

```
var fileContent = await _graphServiceClient.Drives[docFolderId].Items[file.Id].Content.GetAsync();
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
await fileContent.CopyToAsync(ms);
var length = ms.Length;
var bob = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());

string fileDate = "";

if (myRegex != null)
{
    fileDate = myRegex.Match(file.Name).ToString();
}

DAFormFile formfile = new DAFormFile(
    baseStream: bob,
    baseStreamOffset: ms.Position,
    length: length,
    name: fileDate,
    fileName: file.Name
    )
{
    Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
    ContentType = file.File.MimeType == mimeTypeXlsm ? "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
};
```

And here is my code for converting the file to an Excel file:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
{
    //We need to create a read/write memory stream that is needed to read a password protected file
    MemoryStream readWrite = new MemoryStream();
    excelFile.CopyTo(readWrite);
    return new ExcelPackage(readWrite);
}
else
{
    return new ExcelPackage(excelFile.OpenReadStream());
}
```

The IFormFile object that is produced in the first step has a length to it. However, once the file is converted to an Excel file, there are no worksheets. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have a feeling it's with the IFormFile creation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't convert anything. EPPlus can't convert a non-Excel file to Excel. The file is *already* an Excel file. The code you wrote reads an Excel file and saves it again without modification. What are you trying to do? Where did `IFormFile` come from? That's *not* a SharePoint file interface, it's an uploaded file

Comment: No matter where `fileContent`, it already contains an Excel file. Instead of trying to copy `ms` or modify it, just use it, making sure you reset the position. That means, passing `ms` to `baseStream` instead of `bob`

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos - It actually does convert something. The IFormFile is an intermediary, I'm not an expert on that object. What I know is that what I get from SharePoint isn't an Excel file, like mydata.xlsx. It's a stream. And while the data is Excel data, what I need to work with is an Excel Package. The Package contains all the sheets, etc.. So the code does in fact convert an Excel file/stream of data, into an Excel Package.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos - I can't use fileContent as is. When I use that, I get an error from EPPluss that it can't use a closed stream. Once again, fileContent doesn't contain an Excel file, it contains a data stream. In other words, when you look at the properties of fileContent, you won't see a property for WorkBook or WorkSheets. EPPlus takes this and converts it to an Excel Package, which does have those properties. Turns out the issue was exactly what is marked as the answer. I wasn't setting the Offset to 0.

Comment: It's me that needs to say "once again". The ExcelPackage constructor only accepts a stream to an actual Excel file, so your own code proves that whatever `excelFile` is, it opens a stream to a real Excel file. You could just save this to disk directly. The rest of the code has several issues two, right from the 2nd line onwards. Right now you're creating *two identical* copies of the original stream for no reason at all, `ms` and `bob`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating a new instance of `DAFormFile` you set

```
baseStreamOffset: ms.Position
```

I believe that the current position in the stream (`ms.Position`) is set to the end of the stream, so it can affect the rest of the code.

Try to set `baseStreamOffset` to `0`.

Otherwise we need more details. No idea how do you create `excelFile` and how did you implement `DAFormFile`

Comment: Yes, that was absolutely correct! Thank you!